# Rugby Union - Sum Of Binomial Random Variables

Tags: probability

I've been cracking my head at this for a few days now. Suppose a Rugby Union match is expected to have 5.9 tries on average, and tries follow a Poisson distribution. A conversion follows a try, where each conversion follows a binomial distribution with probability "p". Can I use a Poisson distribution to estimate if 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...etc. conversions will be scored in a game?

Comment: I imagine by binomial distribution you mean Bernoulli  ($n=1$). Then under the usual independence assumptions the number of conversions has Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if tries occur with a **Poisson** arrival rate $\lambda$, and conversions follow each try if there is a **Bernoulli** success of rate $p$, then conversions occur with a Poisson arrival rate of $\lambda p$.